# Having a loading message when looping through a set of database queries (mySQL/sqLite)

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, callback

I wish to show a loading message while querying info from a database in sqLite. Here's what I have so far:

```
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Updating Distributor List...", true);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "https:xxxx.php",
        data: { lastUpdated: lastUpdated, section: 'distributors'},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
                $.each(result.response, function(i, val) {
                    db.transaction(function(ctx) {
                        ctx.executeSql("SELECT ID FROM distributors WHERE token = '"+val.ID+"' ", [], function(tx,checkres) { //select all from phoneDB 
                            if(checkres.rows.length) {
                                    tx.executeSql("update distributors set distributorName='"+val.distributorName+"',address='"+val.address+"',postcode='"+val.postcode+"',phone='"+val.phone+"',email='"+val.email+"',lastUpdated='"+val.lastUpdated+"' WHERE token='"+val.ID+"'", []);
                            } else {
                                if(val.deleted != "1") {
                                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO distributors(distributorName,address,postcode,phone,email,lastUpdated,token) VALUES('"+val.distributorName+"','"+val.address+"','"+val.postcode+"','"+val.phone+"','"+val.email+"','"+val.lastUpdated+"','"+val.ID+"')", []);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });     
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();                      
        }
    })
```

So this fires off an AJAX query, and my original thought was to show a loading message before and hide it after the success has completed. But... inside the success callback is another local database query that takes up to 15 seconds to complete. This is also asynchronous so the loading message depends on waiting for these queries to complete.

Also I have about 3 or 4 of these ajax queries all doing pretty much the same thing, so the loading message would change depending on which ajax success callback we are currently in.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick idea. Set 4 gloabal variables. set their values to false.

once the first outer query gets completed set the value of first global variable to true and call a function that that would stop the progresss indicator.

this function will stop the progress indicator only when all the global variables are set to true.

so when all the 4 inner ajax calls gets completed then this function will stop your progress indicator.

I hope you know how to set global variables in javascript

```
function someFunction(){
    this.firstIndicator=false;
    this.secondIndicator=false;
}
```

then you can call the function someFunction.firstIndicator